# How to find variance in Poisson?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

The number of ice creams sold per hour from Mr Fishy’s van is observed to be a Poisson random variable with parameter =8. Each ice cream costs two pounds but Mr Fishy has to pay five pounds per hour for the pitch. What is the variance of his hourly profit (measured in pounds and ignoring all other income and expenses)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.